# Automatically executing code whenever a variable is updated

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, swing

Say I have a program that contains some data.  Some integer values, e.g. {1, 5, 10, 3}.  The program has a GUI that displays the data.  Each integer is converted to string and displayed as a label.  There are several different parts of the program where the data can be changed, e.g. a button that increments a value when clicked.  Each time a value changes the corresponding label must be updated to display the new value.

Perhaps a more common senario: say we have a control that both changes data and displays data, e.g. a slider bar.  Each time the slider is moved we want the data to change, and be displayed in a label (or maybe many different labels).  But there are also other ways the data can change, and when it does the slider bar should move.

For Java Swing, what is the current best practise for doing this automatically so we don't ever forget to update the labels?

Same question for Objective C Cocoa.

Comment: for objective c have a look at properties. They are exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6):

I would first look at the observer design pattern.

You can observe changes in data and update the UI accordingly.  Each language has a different way of implementing it.

Answer (score 6):

I think in Swing the most common approach is to use [PropertyChangeListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in any of the Swing UI widgets. They all have a view side and a model side (e.g. a `JTable` is the view side of a table, where the `TableModel` is the model side).

If you want to make changes to the data, and make sure your UI is updated, you make the changes on the model side and Swing takes care of the rest. You can take the same approach. Have a model to back your view, and make sure all changes happen on the model. The view elements should then register listeners to that model, and update themself whenever it is needed (basically, the Observer pattern as suggested by tjg184)

Answer (score 0):

There is the delegate pattern in Objective c

VariableChanger.h

```
@protocol VariableChangedProtocol

-(void) variableDidChange;

@end

@interface VariableChangerClass : NSObject
{
    id<VariableChangedProtocol> delegate;
    int exampleVariable;
}

@property int exampleVariable;

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<VariableChangedProtocol>) target;

@end
```

---

VariableChanger.m

```
@implementation
@synthesize exampleVariable;

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<VariableChangedProtocol>) target
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        delegate = target;
    }
}

-(void) setExampleVariable:(int) newValue
{
    if(newValue != exampleVariable)
    exampleVariable = newValue;
    [delegate variableDidChange];
}

@end
```

---

VariableChangedListener.m

```
@implementation VariableChangedListener

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
         VariableChangerClass *v = [[VariableChangerClass alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
 }

-(void) variableDidChange
{
    NSLog(@"The variable changed");
}

@end
```